# Disable Back button in Digits

Tags: android, android-navigation, twitter-digits

While doing digits programming, i am using following method :

```
Digits.authenticate(authCallback,R.style.CustomDigitsTheme1);
```

which directs me to digits authentication screen(without showing my xml design file). 
[image]

Now, when i press back button, it shows me my xml with digits auth button as below.
[image]

which i do not want.I tried conventional ways of disabling back buttons but they did not work.  Is there any way i can disable back button on authentication???

Answer (score 0):

You can override when the keyboard disappears using this method:

```
 public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && 
   event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       // Do your thing here
       return false;
  }
 return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

This may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using these

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// your code.
}
```

and for older then API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // your code
    return true;
}

  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```